# Windows 7 Remote Desktop without Dedicated LAN connection

Tags: windows-7, internet, remote-desktop

Is it possible to connect remotely to another pc using Remote desktop or VNC or any other programm without being physically connected to that PC(LAN or WAN)? I want to connect to my pc at home using the internet at work and will use it's IP address as a PC name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using both Remote desktop (assuming Windows!) and/or VNC. The most likely thing that would stop it working are firewall or router rules at either end of the connection. Many office networks block the VNC or RDP ports through the external gateway thus preventing this type of connection. I have also seen many home routers prevent incoming RDP or VNC connections by default to prevent unauthorised attempts at remote control. The ports have to be opened explicitly.

I can't remember the default port numbers for RDP or VNC off the top of my head but it will be easy to look up on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to make sure you're connecting to the ***external IP*** address, not the "internal" IP address (192.168.1.xxx). You can search "what's my IP" on google to find out your external IP address. You then have to ensure that remote desktop sharing is enabled on the home PC. Additionally, you must have a password on your user account to login, or you have to change some policy to allow you to login without a password. If you go that route, let me know and I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp) (currently in beta), but not as smooth an experience as Windows' default solution.